# How to create a simple importable class in Lua?

Tags: lua, lua-table, meta-method

I'd like to create `MyClass` class in Lua in a separate file **myclass.lua** which I can import and use later.
It should be working the following way:

```
local MyClass = require 'myclass'
tab = {1,2,3}
m = MyClass(tab)
```

However, following the code in Lua docs I can't make it work and am getting errors `attempt to call global 'MyClass' (a table value)`.

The code I have written so far for **myclass.lua**:

```
local MyClass = {}
MyClass.__index = MyClass

function MyClass.__init(tab)
    self.tab = tab or {}
    setmetatable({},MyClass)
    return self
end
return MyClass
```

There is a plethora of examples how to write classes in Lua but I don't think I understand the difference and as a result getting lost in the implementation details. Is there a more or less *conventional* way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Lua, you cannot usually call a table like you would call a function. For example, this code will produce an error of "attempt to call local 't' (a table value)".

```
local t = {}
t()
```

There is a way of making this work by using metatables, however.

```
local hello = {}
local mt = {} -- The metatable
mt.__call = function ()
  print("Hello!")
end
setmetatable(hello, mt)
hello() -- prints "Hello!"
```

When you try and call a table as you would a function, Lua first checks to see whether the table has a metatable. If it does, then it tries to call the function in the `__call` property of that metatable. The first argument to the `__call` function is the table itself, and subsequent arguments are the arguments that were passed when the table was called as a function. If the table doesn't have a metatable, or the metatable doesn't have a `__call` function, then an "attempt to call local 't'" error is raised.

Your example code has three problems:

1. You are trying to use `__init` instead of `__call`. Lua doesn't have an `__init` metamethod.
2. `__call` takes different parameters than the ones you are using. The first parameter to the `__call` function is the table itself. You can either use `function MyClass.__call(self, tab)`, or use the colon syntax, `function MyClass:__call(tab)`, which implicitly adds the `self` parameter for you. These two syntaxes are functionally identical.
3. You haven't set a metatable for the `MyClass` table. While you are setting a metatable for MyClass's objects, that doesn't mean that a metatable is automatically set for MyClass itself.

To fix this, you could do something like the following:

```
local MyClass = {}
setmetatable(MyClass, MyClass)
MyClass.__index = MyClass

function MyClass:__call(tab)
    local obj = {}
    obj.tab = tab or {}
    setmetatable(obj, MyClass)
    return obj
end

return MyClass
```

This sets MyClass to use itself as a metatable, which is perfectly valid Lua.

The system of metatables is very flexible, and allows you to have just about any class/object scheme you want. For example, if you want, you can do everything inline.

```
local MyClass = {}

setmetatable(MyClass, {
    __call = function (class, tab)
        local obj = {}
        obj.tab = tab or {}
        setmetatable(obj, {
            __index = MyClass
        })
        return obj
    end
})

return MyClass
```

As well as being concise, this also has the advantage that people can't change the class's metamethods if they have access to the class table.

Comment: That's a slight disadvantage (ok, a major disadvantage) with setting a table's metatable as itself, and setting its __index metamethod to itself. `local obj = MyClass{1, 2, 3}` actually works fine with this code, but then if you try to index `obj.foo`, then it sees that `foo` doesn't exist in `obj`, and then checks the `MyClass` table for `foo` as that's what you set the __index of obj to. It doesn't find `foo` in `MyClass` either, so it looks at `MyClass`'s __index, which is... `MyClass`. Lua is smart enough to detect that this is an infinite loop, so it errors out for you.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `__init` metamethod available for a table. When you do the following:

```
m = MyClass(tab)
```

it looks for the `MyClass.__call` method definition. Just update your `myclass.lua` as:

```
local MyClass = {}
MyClass.__index = MyClass

function MyClass:__call(tab)
    self.tab = tab or {}
    setmetatable({},MyClass)
    return self
end

return MyClass
```

Comment: Yes, but it does not solve the problem with error. Try to import this and call `local m = MyClass({1,2,3})`.

Comment: @minerals First argument to `__call` is the "function" that was called – in this case, the class.  So change it to `function MyClass.__call( _, tab )` here. (If you happen to have "generic" constructors later on, you can give '`_`' a different name & use it to find out which class `__call` should be constructing an instance of.)

Comment: It does not work. I am getting `attempt to call global MyClass` errors.

Comment: @nobody ah, completely forgot about self reference :/ Edited now